# I am trying to connect phpmyadmin database to node js app but but getting error

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, wordpress, backend

I am acually remaking a wordpress site from scratch with React (for frontend) , Node and express (for backend). There are a lot of post on the current wordpress site database and i want to use the same database and will just use Node and express to create, read, update or delete posts. I see the phpmyadmin panel but there is a big mess (3 database and 20+ tables on each database and a lot of entry on each table) of data and i don't know where is the real post and what should i do now. I try this code to connect with the database

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'user_name',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'database name'
});

connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error connecting to the database:', err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connected to the database');
});

module.exports = connection;
```

when i run this code this give me a error

```
Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'my_user_name'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

i am getting all the connection data(user, password, database, host) from wordpress file manager wp-config.php and now don't know how to make the backend with node.

Please anyone know what to do next help me to create the backend

Answer (score 1):

try this approach

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
connectionLimit : 10,
host            : 'localhost',
user            : 'user name',
password        : 'password',
database        : 'database name'

})

  pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if(err) throw err
    console.log(`connected as id ${connection.threadId}`)

    connection.query('SELECT * from users', (err, rows) => {
        connection.release() // return the connection to pool

        if(!err) {
            res.send(rows)
        } else {
            console.log(err)
        }

    })
})
```

Comment: getting this error now 

Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: @MuhammadHossain well you obviously have to replace the fake username in this example with the real username for _your_ database.  We don't know what your credentials are.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. You just have to give you're remote host name which you'll find on cpanel and you have to  add you're local ip adress to the remote mysql host.